# Is it possible to make a Window as the SplashScreen for WPF Project

Tags: wpf, splash-screen

When I use the `AddNewItem` to add an splash screen to a project, It adds an image file to the project. But I want to know if it is possible to make a `Window` as the Splash Screen of a WPF project.

I tried to set the `BuildAction` property of a `Window` to `SplashScreen` but the project fails to compile.

Comment: It seems that you need to read a book about C# and WPF.

Comment: OK. so there is no regular way of doing it. I hope find other ways.

Comment: Do you know how to create a window and show it? No need to search for a 'non-regular' way.

Comment: Every splash screen is just a normal window. You can shape windows any way you like (for non-rectangular splash screens). You just need to know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Andy Lang apparently explained to make the splash screen with this single steps.

Please refer

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38291/Implement-Splash-Screen-with-WPF

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a normal window, put an image inside the window, and show and hide it at appropriate times. No such thing as 'Splash Screen' exists it .NET.